# Is there a way to create a class by refactoring in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I'd like to move some methods into another class. Does Xcode Refactoring have some facility to do that ?

Note: XCode allows to extract method already so why not class. I'm pretty satisfied of XCode it's just a question not a critics :)

Comment: IMO , Xcode and refactoring are a contradiction in terms. When I have to refactor/repurpose intensely, i use AppCode from JetBrains (makers of IntelliJ and other goodies). AppCode is not a replacement for Xcode, but is far superior in coding intensive phases of the projects. I doubt very much Xcode would permit you to extract a section of code into a new class.

Comment: Aren't you just looking for Copy & Paste?

Comment: I was about asking the same. I can't believe XCode is so inferior to eclipse and VisualStudio, when Apple brags so much of doing user friendly software.

Comment: @Kevin: well copy and paste doesn't create FILE for you ;)

Comment: @Mister Smith XCode does extract method pretty well I think even better than Visual Studio. VS 2010 can create class automatically but I don't remember it can really extract class either. As AppCode didn't test it.